# Buttons in table view cells cause unwanted scrolling

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitableview

I have a button in my table view cell so that a user can like a post. Whenever I click the button, the table view scolls a couple cells up. I do not want this scrolling to occur. I also do not have paging enabled so I do not know why this is happening. Does anyone know how I can prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you update the code what you have written in post button click ?

Comment: Currently I am using parse for my backend. I can't upload my actual code but when I click the button, a record is added to my likes table and the count is saved to the corresponding record in my post table. If successful, the table view is reloaded with the new count

Comment: why you are reloading whole tableview just try to reload only the cell you wanted

Comment: Reloading just the individual cell was causing even more problems and I'm not sure why. Right now the only issue I am having is with the scrolling

Comment: Are you trying to call reload data every time user click on Like button?

Comment: yes that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: that is causing the issue of unwanted scrolling trying to reloaddata table every times is causing the issue for scrolling

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have liked on the 3rd row of the UITableView then simple call line like this

**first update your array then call**

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([/*yourindexpath*/],
                        withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

Comment: I just put that in and it works to reload only one cell instead of the whole table view. However, now my cells are being resized (my cells have dynamic heights depending on what is in the cell). I'm still having some unwanted scrolling too

Comment: I can't post my code because it is a private project but you are right that the reload is causing the scrolling. When I take out the call to reload there is no scrolling when a button is pressed (although none of my objects are updated either) so I must be doing something wrong with the way I am reloading the cells

Comment: Are you doing Async ? i mean if any user click on like button are you stopping the user untill response will come ? or user can scroll and click another cell ?

Comment: we aren't stopping the user, they can scroll and click another cell

Comment: then you cant use the reload data you have to remove the reload data and have to update the tableview cell one by one .. i suspect there will be the issue in heightforrowatindexpath .. just a guess